# SSL issue in Android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

We are using HTTPS in our App-Backend communication, it's working perfectly all the time except for two times(so far) where we captured the below error, we are using nginx/PHP and we have bought our certificate and it is supporting Android. The other odd thing is that we can't even find this two bad requests in the access.log, we change the verbosity to debug now so we capture everything in the next few days.

The error below suggests it's a protocol error, the backend is using the same version, nothing has changed.

Has anyone experienced this issue? if yes, is there a solution for it?

**Update**
I just relized that the backend has been updated from sslv3 to TLSv1, not sure why it woks most of the time, shouldn't be failing all the time? is there something that we need to do after using TSLv1?

This is code I'm using,

```
public byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return null;
        }

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

And this is the error,

```
10-24 12:54:28.749:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x7761c840: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
10-24 12:54:28.749:  error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x75bf6d90:0x00000003)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:440)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at com.herb.android.HttpHelper.getUrlBytes(HttpHelper.java:62)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at com.herb.android.NetworkThread.access$1(NetworkThread.java:976)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at com.herb.android.NetworkThread$1.handleMessage(NetworkThread.java:210)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
10-24 12:54:28.749:  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x7761c840: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
10-24 12:54:28.749:  error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x75bf6d90:0x00000003)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
10-24 12:54:28.749:     ... 16 more
```